# Free memory in a loop regardless of return code

Tags: c, loops, error-handling, goto

I have the following C pseudo code:

```
int main()
{
    int rc = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        char *data = malloc(i); // Each iteration has a different alloc size

        rc = do_something(data);
        if (rc != 0) goto cleanup;

        rc = do_something_else();
        if (rc != 0) goto cleanup;

cleanup:
        free(data);
        if (rc != 0) break;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

I want to emulate Python's `try...finally` pattern by breaking out of a loop if a called function returns an error, but only after doing some necessary cleanup work.

So far the code looks OK to me but I'm new to C. Is there a different pattern that avoids the repeated `rc != 0` test after `free`? (I am aware that some people consider `goto` unconditionally wrong but I see it as the cleanest solution I found for this case.)

Comment: You can add `rc != 0` into the `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 10 && rc != 0; i++)`... just initialise `rc=1;` instead of 0. In such case you won't need the `break`

Comment: @AlexLop. Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the specific code/case you have shown, you can remove the need for any sort of per-loop clean-up by using the [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function instead of `malloc`. This will simply replace the memory allocated on the previous loop (if there is one) with a new block (of different size). You can then simply defer any clean-up (i.e. calling `free`) to outside the loop.

You can still use the `break` statements to exit the loop whenever an error occurs; or, as mentioned in the comments, you could add an `rc != 0` test to the loop's condition.

Here's some C code that will do as I have indicated (but, of course, you will need actual *definitions* of the two called fucntions for it to work):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int do_something(char* data);
int do_something_else(void);

int main()
{
    int rc = 0;
    char* data = NULL;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        char* temp = realloc(data, i); // If "data" is NULL (1st loop) -> same as malloc
        if (temp == NULL) { // Allocation failure...
            // Error message
            break;
        }
        data = temp; // Succesfull allocation, so update "data" pointer

        rc = do_something(data);
        if (rc != 0) break;

        rc = do_something_else();
    }
    free(data); // We now only have to do the cleanup once (calling with NULL is allowed).
    return rc;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: This is even better than my answer.

Comment: This is very appealing and might apply to my *real* code, where the alloc and free calls are in a separate functions, but it raises a broader question: is there any concern replacing malloc with realloc in the called function, which is generic and is called in a wide range of contexts?

Comment: @user3758232 If you're always going to have a *cyclic* pattern of `malloc ... free` then replacing that with `realloc` (in the cycle) and a single `free` *after* the cycle is not changing the overall behaviour pattern (so long as the relevant precautions are taken against a failed call to `realloc`, as I have shown in my code).

Comment: @user3758232 Also, if you pass a pointer to a function that uses `realloc`, then you would have to pass a *pointer-to-pointer* to have the modified value returned to the caller. But that probably is also the case when you use `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the variable outside the loop. Then just null the variable whenever you free it, and check for this after the loop.

```
    char *data = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        data = malloc(i); // Each iteration has a different alloc size

        rc = do_something(data);
        if (rc != 0) break;

        rc = do_something_else();
        if (rc != 0) break;

        free(data);
        data = NULL;
    }
    if (data) {
        free(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to use such pattern (with `goto`) in cases when resource management is required and there is a set of checks to be performed while each failure requires to stop the flow and perform the required cleanup.

To make the code cleaner, in my opinion, would be to place the `rc != 0` condition inside the `for` loop:

```
int rc = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && rc != 0; i++)
{
    ...
```

In such case you won't need the `break` at all as the loop would stop anyway once `rc` is compared to 0. I would also recommend check the resut of `malloc`:

```
int foo(void)
{
    int rc = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10 && rc != 0; i++) {
        char *data = malloc(i); // Each iteration has a different alloc size
        if (!(rc = !!data)) goto cleanup;

        rc = do_something(data);
        if (rc != 0) goto cleanup;

        rc = do_something_else();
        if (rc != 0) goto cleanup;

cleanup:
        free(data);
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Note that it is completely legal to `free` a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: I had already accepted an answer, but this is actually the most versatile one because it applies to situations not  specific to `alloc` / `realloc` or where I can't modify that code.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience there rarely is a truly simple solution to this kind of problem with error handling in C.

You could do something like this, but it is arguable if this really is better.

```
int main()
{
    int rc = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        char *data = malloc(i); // Each iteration has a different alloc size

        rc = do_something(data);
        if (rc != 0) goto cleanup;

        rc = do_something_else();
        if (rc != 0) goto cleanup;
        
        free(data);
        continue;

cleanup:
        free(data);
        break;
    }
    return rc;
}
```